# Shuffle function in swift seems to remove cards instead of swapping them

Tags: swift

I am examining the shuffle function below given by a colleague in an interview question to shuffle a deck of cards. It seems to me that the card at the original index "from" will be removed and lost. Instead of being swapped, it is getting removed. Am I missing something?

```
func shuffle() {
        var from = 0
        var to = 0
        for _ in cards {
            from = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))
            to = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))
            cards.insert(cards.remove(at: from), at: to)
        }
        print("\nShuffled deck\n")
    }
```

Comment: What do you think that call to `cards.insert` does?

Answer (score 0):

`Array`'s `remove(at:)` function doesn't just remove an item from the array; it also returns the removed element. The code above immediately passes that removed element to `insert(at:)`, which causes the removed element to be inserted somewhere else.

Comment: Yes. So remove returns the element at index "from" and inserts it at index "to". What happens to the element that was already there in index "to"?

Comment: The `insert(at:)` method shifts everything to the right of the insertion point to the right by one position.